# checking the SQLite Connection Pool

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I understand that a connection must be open for the locked error to appear, however through trying find where this connection is open i noticed this error appear.

> SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for
>   +data+user+0+com_xxxx_xxxxx+databases+xxxxxxx has been closed but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as they are
>   released back to the pool.

is there a way to view current connection or completely stop all connection, as trying to find where this open connection is driving me mad.